# PHP preg_match_all fails with 2 arguments

Tags: php, regex

i've got the variable $randomWiki with the following String :

```
[...]"wgNamespaceNumber":0,"wgPageName":"Busfahrer","wgTitle":"Busfahrer","wgCurRevisionId"[...]
```

And want to get the "wgTitle" out of it. 
I built the following regex:

```
preg_match_all("/\"wgTitle\":\"(.*?)\"/", $randomWiki);
```

var_dump is giving me bool(false). 
I've already checked the regex with an online tool and it worked.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: your string looks like a json string, try to use `json_decode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this code :

```
$str = '"wgNamespaceNumber":0,"wgPageName":"Busfahrer","wgTitle":"Busfahrer","wgCurRevisionId"';

preg_match_all("#\"wgTitle\":\"([^\"]*)\"#", $str, $res);
var_dump($res);
```

**preg_match_all** accepts 3 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
\"wgTitle\":\"(\w)*\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with  **positive assertion** `?=`:

```
$str = '"wgNamespaceNumber":0,"wgPageName":"Busfahrer","wgTitle":"Busfahrer","wgCurRevisionId"';

// it matches the word followed by separator ," - which is the boundary of the next key
preg_match_all("/\"wgTitle\":\"(\w+)\"(?=,\")/iu", $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]); 

// the output:
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Busfahrer"
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php